# Cannot change the default font in TailwindCSS

Tags: css, fonts, tailwind-css

TailwindCSS is [very clear](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/font-family#customizing-the-default-font) on how to change the default font for the whole application:

> For convenience, **Preflight** sets the font family on the `html` element to match your configured sans font, so one way to change the default font for your project is to customize the sans key in your `fontFamily` configuration:

In an application I started from scratch, I did that and added to the main page (this is a Vite/Vue3 project that starts by default with an `App.vue` page and everything is routed from there)

```css
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;0,1000;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900;1,1000&display=swap');
</style>
```

Together with

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
export default {
  content: [
    "./index.html",
    "./src/**/*.{vue,js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['Nunito', 'sans-serif'],
      }
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

in `tailwind.config.js` it was perfect: `Nunito` was the default font.

Fast forward to today, I am with a simple app (again Vite/Vue3) I develop for some time and I decided to change the default font by exactly following the same two steps.

**My problem: the default font does not change.**

I tried to remove the cache, restart the application, use a browser I never used - nothing helps.

I added, for debugging purposes, to `App.vue` (the topmost app where the loading of the font happens)

```css
<style>
div {
    font-family: 'Nunito';
}
</style>
```

Here the font changed (on `<div>` at least but this is more or less how apps today are structured - so in practice this was the whole app). So the font is present as expected.

When inspecting an element, I see that the computed font is set on `<html>`

```css
font-family: ui-sans-serif, system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
```

and it is likely that this is what is set by Tailwind's Preflight.

**Is there something I forgot?**

Comment: Consider checking `sans: ['Nunito', 'sans-serif'],` is set in your Tailwind configuration. Otherwise, consider providing a minimal reproducible example that reproduces the unexpected behavior.

Comment: @Wongjn: I am not sure I understand: isn't the `tailwind.config.js` I provided correct? It will be difficult to provide a minimal reproducible example as starting from scratch was fine. I am looking for what I missed in the configuration.

Comment: The `tailwind.config.js` would be correct, but as you stated, this was from an application you started from scratch, not the Tailwind configuration in the project that is exhibiting the problem. You haven't missed anything in the configuration from what I can see It will be difficult to offer any assistance if only correct code is provided and code with the mistake(s) is not provided.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to apply `class="font-sans"` to the highest `<div>` in order to actually have the font used in the application.
Not really sure why this is needed.